# Get an array of values using fetch api javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using fetch api to read a txt file via javascript. I want to load the contents of the txt file which are separated by new line in an array.

Text file:

```
A
B
C
```

I need it in the following format:

```
arr = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Below is the code I tried

```
var arr = []
fetch('file.txt')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
arr.push(text)
console.log(text)

    });
  console.log(arr)
```

Nothing gets added to my array, however the data from the text file gets printed on the console.

Comment: How do you know that nothing is added?

Comment: The console.log(arr) prints an empty array

Comment: have you done a `console.log(arr)`?

Comment: @mmenschig yes, on the last line of code

Comment: Move `log(arr)` right after `log(text)` to see the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the text response to an array by splitting on newline characters:

```js
function fetchData() {
    return fetch('data.txt')
            .then(response =>
                response.text().then(text => text.split(/\r|\n/)));
}

fetchData().then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

Comment: I still cant access this arr outside the fetch. Why?

Comment: Thats because fetch is going to return a promise, and JavaScript does not wait for it to complete before moving on. This would be a good spot to use `async/await` if you want this code to function synchronously. I'll update the answer to give a full example.

Comment: What I don't understand, why do we need 2x `.then()`, why couldn't we just contain everything in the first?

Comment: response.text() returns another promise. i updated the example with a more concise version.